# checkbox check change does not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to implement `checkbox` on `change` in jQuery, `checkbox` checked state is working properly but when it is `unchecked` it does not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.chk').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
        if (selectitem != 0) {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem - 1);
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').hide(200);
        }
    } else {
        var selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem + 1);
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').show(200);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem.... which part is not working... can you share the html sample as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use on change event instead of click event handler. On change event will give you the changed state i.e. checked  or unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.chk').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
        if (selectitem != 0) {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem - 1);
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').hide(200);
        }
    } else {
        var selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem + 1);
        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').show(200);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Selected Products value pulse on checked but it not minus on unchecked

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle link?

Comment: jsfiddle  it working but it's code cannot working on my asp.net website  Link :--  http://jsfiddle.net/piyush_kanpariya/79vp0f1r/

Comment: please check console log error, i think your css and other js files are not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event of `checkbox` to check if `checkbox` is `checked` or `unchecked`

```
$('.chk').change(function () {
 if(this.checked)
//your code
 else
//your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state of checkbox using jquery
[check box state](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzBsnDXNhNw)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="eva-accordion" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpCategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpProducts_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <a class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#">
                                    <h3><%# Eval("category_name") %></h3>
                                    <h6 style="display: none;" class="select">Selected Products ( <span class="selectitem">0</span> )
                                    </h6>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="<%# divGetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="No record found..." Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                                    <div class="span12 marb20 marl0">
                                                        <div class="span1" style="text-align: center !important;">
                                                            No.
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span3 marl0">
                                                            Products Name
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            Tablets
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            Capsules
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            Injection
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            Strength
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span1 pull-right" style="text-align: center !important;">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                                    <div class="span12 marb20 marl0">
                                                        <div class="span1" style="text-align: center !important;">
                                                            <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span3 marl0">
                                                            <%# Eval("product_name") %>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            <%# Eval("tablets") %>&nbsp;
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            <%# Eval("capsules") %>&nbsp;
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            <%# Eval("injection") %>&nbsp;
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span2 marl0">
                                                            <%# Eval("strength") %>&nbsp;
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="span1 pull-right" style="text-align: center !important;">
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" ValidationGroup='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' CssClass="chk" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.chk').change(function () {
                if (!$(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                    selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
                    if (selectitem != 0) {
                        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem - 1);
                        selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
                        if (selectitem == 0) {
                            $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').hide(200);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').hide(200);
                        selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
                    }

                } else {
                    var selectitem = parseInt($(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text());
                    $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.selectitem').text(selectitem + 1);
                    $(this).closest('.accordion-group').find('.select').show(200);
                }
            });
        });
```